Проблема с выводом при чтении txt файла
Код:
if choose == '3':
    os.chdir('bd')
    os.chdir('email')
    email = input('Введи почту:')
    c = 0
    with open('Налогоплательщики_2022_60M.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            c += line.count(email)
    print(f'Количество совпадений: {c}')
    input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
    if email in line:
        print(line.strip())        

И принт просто ничего не выводит хотя совпадение находит тоесть количество

Ну и касательно if email in line: не забывайте, что вы выполняете это после цикла, а значит line содержит последнюю строку файла, а ведь никто не обещал, что email будет находиться именно в последней строке

@andreymal Да блин был черновик старый задал вопрос и не доглядел, а как можно сделать чтобы после input("Для вывода нажми Enter...") смог вывести?
